# Hooking up a rotary encoder to raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, hardware, rpi.gpio, sensor, connection

There are a ton of questions on this, and I'm pretty new at working with rotary encoders.  I purchased this one [Taiss E38S6-600-24G](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MX1SYXB), thinking (incorrectly I might add) that it would be a simple thing to connect and read the position.  The encoder itself will be used to measure the length of a cord pulled through a machine, allowing the machine to stop pulling when a length is reached.  I'm planning on using a simple wheel system on the encode and connecting it to a separate power source.

I've since found that it the Pi will probably not read the correct counts and will more then likely miss some, due to other processes running on it.

I've seen where people use external counter boards then query them as to the position, or use the Pigpio system to get the counts.

I'll admit this is my mistake, as I didn't do enough research before purchasing it, although I have been working on it since.

My question is this, what is the best way to use the encoder and ensure that no counts are missed?  Separate board, Pigio, something else?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Opinion questions generally get deleted (or responses by the uninformed). Explain what you tried and examples of results. A properly constructed pulse counter should not lose pulses.

Comment: Any microcontroller e.g. Pico would probably be more suitable (and cheaper) than a CPU.